# How to set minimum size of scrollbar thumb slider on SWT ScrollBar?

Tags: java, windows-xp, nattable

Specifically on a Windows XP machine, The width of the SWT ScrollBar Slider becomes incredibly thin when the internal scroll composite is very large. Is there a way to set the minimum width of the thumb slider to like 10-15px so that it doesn't get that thin? My specific case with this is when using NatTables with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar in NatTable is managed by the `ViewportLayer`. It internally uses instances of `ScrollBarScroller` for this, which are wrappers around a `ScrollBar`. To support custom scrollbars like the one posted in the other answer, the `ViewportLayer` supports that you set a custom `ScrollBarScroller`. This is explained in one of my blog posts here: [NatTable with custom scrollbars](http://blog.vogella.com/2015/01/26/nattable-with-custom-scrollbars/).

You could for example set a customized instance of `ScrollBarScroller` where you override `#setThumb(int)` and there you ensure that the value of the thumb never gets below a certain minimum. Not sure if that would have any side effects on scrolling. But it should be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't think you can do that, because the Scrollbar it's drawn by the OS.
I think you have two options here, if you really need this feature:

1) implement you custom Scrollbar.

2) try to use/modify an existing custom Scrollbar, for instance this one: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/17/sacrilege-custom-swt-scrollbar/